# Is this the right statement for string comparison of two strings?

Tags: c, strcmp

```
if(strcmp(p[pas].origin,"West")&&strcmp(p[pas].destination,"East")==0)
      {
       cost[pas]=5.62+5.62;
      }
```

is this the right code for the two input strings? or is there something wrong since the program runs but i cannot get the return value

Comment: There is not enough information in this question for us to help you. Until you explain what you're asking -1. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't run but should be like this

```
if((strcmp(p[pas].origin,"West")==0) && (strcmp(p[pas].destination,"East")==0)
      {
       cost[pas]=5.62+5.62;
      }
```

Comment: thanks! i got it working and returned the correct value